# Fancybox 2 issue

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I am facing a weird issue with the new Fancybox 2

I am getting multiple sets of thumbnails for a particular image, i cross verified whether i am populating multiple images with my code, but that's not the case.

here are the urls : 
http://test.tendencewatches.com/construction/

click on press and then click on any small images, you will see whats happening.

I have implemented the same thing here (same exact code) : http://test.tendencewatches.com/construction/press/

and it works perfectly fine. In a pickle!!

Please help

Comment: i have changed th thumbnail view from the main site right now,but the issue still prevails, if i include in on the overlay, the thumbnails set is replicated twice

Answer (score 1):

Your site is behaving like the fancybox css file is not loaded (Firefox's add-on JSView doesn't detect it) and it might be because you are trying to load it like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="press/text/css" href="press/source/jquery.fancybox.css" media="screen" />
```

I guess this part is the culprit

```
type="press/text/css"
```

it should be `type="text/css"`, shouldn't be?

Comment: I changed it, but it didnt help :(

Comment: works fine for me in firefox and chrome ... IE throws a js error (here:$(function(){ $('#counter').countdown({ image: 'img/digits1800.png', startTime: '00:03:21:08' });});) so it breaks (IE is pickier and doesn't tolerate errors other browsers may overlook)